# transferring string in another place JAVA

Tags: java, swing, textarea, textfield

I use Eclipse oxygen.
how can I "transfert" what i write in a textfield in the textarea?
pls show me how to do it because this is the third day that i study java and i'ts not easy for me to do these things.
i study java at school.

```
package layout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Acquisti");
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 300);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2)); 
        p1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Products");
        p1.add(l1);

        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Price");
        p1.add(l2);

        JTextField tx1 = new JTextField(5);
        p1.add(tx1);

        JTextField tx2 = new JTextField(5);
        p1.add(tx2);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); 
        p2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Lista");
        p2.add(l3);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("ADD");
        p2.add(b1);

        JTextArea tx = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        p2.add(tx);

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        frame.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Valuta");
        p3.add(l4);

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("Lire");
        p3.add(rb1);

        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("Euro");
        p3.add(rb2);

        JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Totale");
        p3.add(l5);

        JTextArea tx3 = new JTextArea(5,5);
        p3.add(tx3);

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        frame.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("SAVE");
        p4.add(b2);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

FOR EXAMPLE!!
everytime i write something in the first textfield "tx1", the string goes to the textarea by pressing enter

Comment: `tx.setText( tx1.getText() );` but it's not clear what you are actually trying to do, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: FOR EXAMPLE!!
everytime i write something in the first textfield "tx1", the string goes to the textarea by pressing enter

Comment: How to write an ActionListener: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html  How to use JTextField: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for a working example that does exactly what you want. `this is the third day that i study java` - I suggest you keep a link to the tutorial since it contains all the basics of using Swing components.

Comment: *"this is the third day that i study java"* Then you should still be sorting out the basics of the language in command-line applications!

Answer (score 0):

After defining tx1 and tx2 add a listener to tx1

```
    tx1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tx2.setText(tx1.getText()); //updates tx2 when you press enter 
        }
    });
```

An alternative shorter syntax using lambda expression :

```
    tx1.addActionListener( e-> tx2.setText(tx1.getText()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

define tx1 and tx2 then add a listener to tx1

```
tx1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tx2.setText(tx1.getText()); //get new value into tx2 when you hit enter 
    }
});
```

otherwise....
you can go through simplified way using lambda expression.....

```
tx1.addActionListener( e-> tx2.setText(tx1.getText()) );
```